# correlation in r with survey data

Tags: r, correlation, survey

I have two columns of survey data. To get the chi-square values, I can use:

> chisq.test(dat$colA, dat$colB)

for which the output might be

> X-squared = 20, df = 5, p-value = 0.2909

How do I get the correlation between the two columns, with a value between -1 and 1?

Thanks.

Comment: fwiw, if your survey data comes from a complex sample, you need to use R's `survey` package :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `cor(dat$colA, dat$colB)`

Comment: Output is NA. What does that imply?

Comment: That you have missing values in the columns... See `?cor`